# How to map two-letter country codes to Emoji?

Tags: go, unicode, emoji

Anyone fiddled with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol? I am wondering how to get US printed as a flag

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    t, err := template.New("").Parse(`
    <p>{{ .Country }}</p>
    <p>Want </p>
    `)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]interface{}{
        "Country": "US",
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/UErXxL645rV

IIUC I need to add 0x1F1A5 to capital latin letters, but I don't how to do this in Go.

Update: Eric Hill suggested: https://play.golang.org/p/hEsScaZSh1I .. can anyone come up with improvements?

Comment: Put your code in the question. Playground links (any links, really) tend to go stale, which will render this question worthless later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only improvements I would recommend is adding verification that the input characters is a pair of ASCII uppercase letters.  Here is an example of what the template function would look like:

```
func(x string) (string, error) {
    if len(x) != 2 {
        return "", errors.New("country code must be two letters")
    }
    if x[0] < 'A' || x[0] > 'Z' || x[1] < 'A' || x[1] > 'Z' {
        return "", errors.New("invalid country code")
    }
    return string(''+rune(x[0])-'A') + string(''+rune(x[1])-'A'), nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Nkg23qsr2Ga

Answer (score 1):

You can use [enescakir/emoji](https://github.com/enescakir/emoji) package. It makes emoji usage easier in Golang.

It can generate country flag emoji from [ISO 3166 Alpha2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) codes.

```golang
emoji.CountryFlag("us") // 
emoji.CountryFlag("gb") //
```